# Dealing with null values from DB

Tags: c#, .net

The db I am querying from is returning some null values.
How do I safeguard against this and make sure the caller gets some data back.

The code I have is:

Using DataReader

```
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            vo = new PlacementVO();
            vo.PlacementID = dr.GetString(0);
```

If I use dataset, I can do it like this.

```
 obj.email = (row["email"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : Convert.ToString(row["email"]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `IsDBNull(int ordinal)` if you are using ordinals (which you are).

So:

```
string email = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader.GetString(0);
```

If you are working with string column names, then to use this you'll have to call `GetOrdinal` first, for example:

```
string GetSafeString(this IDataReader reader, string name)
{
    int index = reader.GetOrdinal(name);
    return reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader.GetString(0);
}
```

Of course, it is faster to only look up ordinals once, not once per row.

A similar approach can be used for `int?` etc, or using a default instead of a null.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add **isnull**(*column which can be null* , *replacement when it is null*) to the actual SQL query. Less code and works without doing anything in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper class to perform this functionality. An example [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/NullableReaders.aspx). The [CSLA framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) I believe also has this functionality